# How to handle an async function called by an event?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, event-handling, catch-block

Let's say I have async function named 'Main' that gets called during page load like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', Main);
```

Since `Main` is an async function, I'd like to catch errors from its promise chain by appending `.catch((e)=>{ console.error(e);});`. However, I don't think that plays nice with `window.addEventListener` (which returns undefined) and expects only the function's assignment as the 2nd argument.

Is it possible to handle promise rejections of Main without creating a wrapper function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use a wrapper function, or
2. Handle all errors within `Main` using `try`/`catch`

For instance:

```
window.addEventListener("load", evt => {
    Main(evt).catch(err => {
        //...handle/report error...
    });
});
```

or in `Main`:

```
async function Main(evt) {
    try {
        // ...your logic...
    } catch (e) {
        //...handle/report error...
    }
}
```

In both cases, make sure the "handle/report error" code itself never throws an error. :-)

Comment: Hey! Loving that [book](https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Toys-T-J-Crowder/dp/1119367956/) so far!